# Google Maps "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Tags: android, google-maps

I got this Error Message as follows when I try to get routes between two points. i regenerated my API key but does't worked.

```
{   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your rate-limit for this API. We      recommend registering for a key at the Google Developers Console:   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=_",   "routes" : [],     "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"}
```

Is there any solution for this.

Comment: you need create a billing account for your google account

Comment: I am currently using free version. the actual problem i am facing is that my is live on Play Store and in old versions there is a code which call the API too many times and too fast. I fixed that issue in the latest version but due to the old version users the app is not working properly.

Comment: google must need the billing account on nowadays use follow the link  https://console.cloud.google.com/billing/ once added it will be working fine.

Comment: $300 credit for free Sign up and get $300 to spend on Google Cloud Platform over the next 12 months.

Comment: No autocharge after free trial ends they ask you for your credit card to make sure you are not a robot. You won’t be charged unless you manually upgrade to a paid account.

Comment: There is no longer a "free" version.  You **must** now enable billing with a credit card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read 
[**`Usage Limits for Google Maps Platform Web Services`**](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/articles/usage-limits)

**`OVER_DAILY_LIMIT`** indicates any of the following:

- The API key is missing or invalid.
- [**`Billing`**](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project) has not been enabled on your account.

**FYI**

Within the next 24 hours, if the error was received because your application sent too many requests per day. The daily quotas are reset at midnight.

**Solutions**

Increasing usage limits, when possible, by purchasing additional allowance for your Google Maps APIs for Work license.

Comment: I am currently using free version. the actual problem i am facing is that my is live on Play Store and in old versions there is a code which call the API too many times and too fast. I fixed that issue in the latest version but due to the old version users the app is not working properly

Comment: Do i have to pay for that ?

Comment: @TariqUrRehman yes. read https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project

Comment: The main problem is none of my Apps are working. I generated all the API keys separately. i get the same response every where i.e in another i am trying to get hotels around my current location.

Comment: @TariqUrRehman `I generated all the API keys separately. i get the same response` .. hahaha, Kindly billing from your account pleease.

Comment: @TariqUrRehman rate chart  https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/?__utma=102347093.43738963.1492062923.1539339051.1539339051.1&__utmb=102347093.0.10.1539339051&__utmc=102347093&__utmx=-&__utmz=102347093.1539339051.1.1.utmcsr=google|utmccn=(organic)|utmcmd=organic|utmctr=(not%20provided)&__utmv=-&__utmk=120111496&_ga=2.31516413.2121447840.1539332068-43738963.1492062923